# Is there a way to change the theme color for our modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme, modern-pages, new-experience

I am working on a modern page inside my classic team site collection. now the modern page will have the light-green color, for the following components; "Feedback", "Edit", the selected line inside the News web part & the slider paging for our event web part, and other parts...,as follow:-

[image]

&

[image]

so is there a way to change this color to match our company official color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the SharePoint Color Palette Tool to change the color in the modern page.

And you could download the SharePoint Color Palette Tool from the URL below.

[SharePoint Color Palette Tool.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182)

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[How To: Change the Color in the SharePoint Online Modern Experience.](http://itgroove.net/align/change-color-spo-modern-experience/)

[Change the color of SharePoint modern experience automatically.](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/12/05/change-the-color-of-sharepoint-modern-experience-automatically/)